# Windows Presentation Foundation How to add items to Listview using code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, dynamically-generated

i want to add Items to my Listview, which i create dynamically using C#.
It looks kinda like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListView test = new ListView();
test.Margin = new Thickness(28 + i, 23,485 - i, 23);
test.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
test.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
test.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
Grid.SetColumn(test,1);
Grid.SetRow(test,1);
```

Now obviously the Listviews i create are completely empty.

So again my question: Is there any posibility to add items (say from an object) and display them in those Listviews i create here?

Comment: I would recommend learn about MVVM, and binding concepts for WPF. you can bind an object, a collection of data and most certainly read through about ObservableCollection. Coz, that would be one of the next stops for you to understand on how to update the UI based on the data changes and collection updates. I would recommend, to do some learning and research on this.

Comment: @IRezzet - See the following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882264/adding-items-to-a-listview-in-c-sharp-in-a-wpf-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882264/adding-items-to-a-listview-in-c-sharp-in-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 0):

*Ques : Is there any posibility to add items (say from an object) and display them in those Listviews i create here?*

Let's say you get a list of string from an object. Like, `objectMain.stringlist` where `objectMain` is your object and `stringlist` is a property (`List<string>`) inside your object. Then, you can assign it like, `test.ItemsSource = objectMain.stringlist`

Using code behind is not recommended. Try using MVVM and create UIElements from the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you use MVVM patern to bind a list to `ItemsSource` in ListView and do that in xaml, but in code it is still available manually.

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Something" });
test.View = gv;
test.Items.Add("Data1");
```